# Letter counting application

Tags: java, string, char

```
package jdaprogrammingactivity22;

/*
 *@Title: JDAProgrammingAssignment4
 *@Description:  Create a program the will count and display a table
 * showing occurrence of each letter in the inputted word/phrase/sentence. 
 * The letters should be sorted in alphabetical order
 *
 * @author Jan Dierekh B. Arroyo
 * Date: Created: July 28, 2019
 *
 */


import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;


public class JDAProgrammingActivity22 {


static void header()
{
     String s = "LETTER COUNTING APPLICATION";
     out.println(s);
     for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
     {
         out.print("-");
     }
     out.println();

} 


static void input()
{
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   out.print("Enter a word/phrase/sentence: ");
   String str1 = scan.nextLine();
   toUpCase(str1);

   out.println(">> Unique Letters:");
   String sort = sortStr(str1);

   out.println("Sorted String: " + sort);

   uniqueLetter(sort);

} 

static String sortStr(String str1)
{ 
    char tempArray[] = str1.toCharArray(); 
        Arrays.sort(tempArray); 

   return new String(tempArray);         
}


static void toUpCase(String str1)
{
    str1 = str1.toUpperCase();
    out.println(">> Word/Phrase/Sentence: ");
    out.println("\t" + str1 + "\n");
}       

static void uniqueLetter(String str1)
{
    int num = 0,COUNT = 0;
    String line = "\t+-----+--------+-------+";
    out.println(line);
    out.println("\t| NO. | LETTER | COUNT | ");
    out.println(line);

    String[] words = str1.split("\\s+");

    for (String word : words) {
        out.println("\t| " + num + " |" + word  + " | " + COUNT + " | ");
    }  

}        

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        header();

        input();




    }

}
```

I'm making a program that will count and display a table showing occurrence of each letter in the inputted word/phrase/sentence. The letters should be sorted in alphabetical order.

I already sorted the string and change it to upperCase because it was required and I already have a counting Algorithm of the occurrence of a character a string.

My problem is on the the desired output, you can look at the expected outcome. I don't know how to output it on a table and put the character. Please help.

I already tried switch to check each character but I don't know how to check the character in a string using switch.

[image]

[Expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypKsx.png)

```
int num,count;
char letter;

String line = "\t+-----+--------+-------+";
out.println(line);
out.println("\t| NO. | LETTER | COUNT | ");
out.println(line);

for(int i = 0; i >= str1.length(); i++)
{
 out.println("\t| " + num + " |" + LETTER + " | " + COUNT + " | ");      
}
```

Comment: Give all your code, without it's hard to provide an answer

Comment: I don't know how to input all of my code, it doesn't accept methods or functions somehow and it's annoying because I don't know how to, and the expected and the code seems like on the wrong place

Comment: How do I add the full code should I add a  notepad? so you can see. Help me guys it's been hours and my brains is already short circuiting.

Comment: 1) You need to right-align the count. Don't use concatenation, but string formatting, like %3d (where 3 is the field width) 2) You need to count the appearance of each character. You should use a HashMap and increase the value if the character is already in it, add any character not yet encountered. Is there any constraint in your case (like ASCII only, or capital letters only)? If not, you nead to deal with unicode characters.

Comment: Click edit, and add your code

Comment: There is no logic to split by letter and count occurence here

Answer (score 0):

Use a map for your letters and counts. If you use a `TreeMap`, it will be sorted by the key by default. So you do not need to sort the characters before.

```
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Character ch : str1.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
       Integer count = map.getOrDefault(ch, 0);
       map.put(ch, count + 1);
    }
    int no = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       no ++;
       Character ch = entry.getKey();
       Integer count = entry.getValue();
       // output your values here
    }
```